# SQL SERVER error la subconsulta devuelve mas de un valor

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

*Intento ejecutar en mi base de datos de SQL server esta consulta pero no se como resolver el problema  de :*
**La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión.**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
if((SELECT  SUM([OrderDetails].Quantity) FROM Products,[OrderDetails]
WHERE Products.ProductID = [OrderDetails].ProductID GROUP BY Products.ProductName
HAVING SUM([OrderDetails].Quantity)=(SELECT MAX(QR.Cantidad) FROM (SELECT Products.ProductName,SUM([OrderDetails].Quantity) AS Cantidad FROM Products,[OrderDetails]
 WHERE Products.ProductID = [OrderDetails].ProductID
 GROUP BY Products.ProductName) AS QR))<1600)
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
  ELSE 
  ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: Bienvenido  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Esta consulta: `SELECT SUM([OrderDetails].Quantity) .... GROUP BY Products.ProductName` devuelve más de una fila y el `IF` solo puede evaluar un único valor